# Unity C# - Stop execution of an IJobParallelFor prior to completion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing, jobs

I'm creating a Unity Job that runs a massive amount of calculations for each input. Passing in 1330 inputs takes 600 seconds total when splitting the inputs up amongst the **IJobParallelFor** job in size 256 batches.

The job works, and after it kicks off, I use a Coroutine on the main thread to check if the job is completed, and then call job.Complete() to pass the result back to the main thread.
Now Unity doesn't freeze! yay! **However**, if I press the play-button within the editor again to stop Unity's execution, the job continues to run and will freeze Unity until it completes.

I can't find any documentation, or any way, to forcibly stop the execution of these jobs. I use OnDisable() to call job.Complete() and dispose of the NativeArray's there. But most importantly, I just need these jobs to stop running. Is there any way to manually stop the execution?

Thanks!

Comment: The IJobParallelFor interface most certainly assigns work to worker threads via the `JobHandle.ScheduleBatchedJobs()`  command. The only coroutine running is on the main thread which looks for `JobHandle.IsCompleted()` and once true, calls `JobHandle.Complete()` to join the results back to the main thread. I understand Coroutines do not spawn additional threads. This post is aimed at looking for a way to force-stop the execution of the separately threaded IJob.

Comment: my mistake good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any way of cancelling a job in progress, but while it's entirely possible that this is either a bug or an oversight, I think you may need to consider the possibility that you're using the job system for something it isn't designed for. Unity's job system appears to be designed primarily to help with parallelization within the new [Data Orientated Tech Stack](https://unity.com/dots), which is probably meant to operate on a time scale of *frames*, not minutes.

Your problem might be far better suited for .NET's parallelization tools, namely things like [Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) and [Parallel.ForEach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop) in conjunction with [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop).

Comment: I hadn't realized this was available in .NET 4! I read some time ago that Unity intended on supporting long running jobs, but that stance may have shifted, so this is most certainly the better way to handle this for now. Thanks!